# How to replace the currnt user logon picture windows Vista+

Tags: windows

I am trying to change the current user logon picture in Windows Vista+
I can't figure out where it is located.

i googled but all the result take about changing the default account pictures.

is there an API to do that or changing some values in the registry ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

OK first of all, if its the user picture do this:

Press the WIN key and click on the user picture you have now
Then click on something like "Change User Picture" from the list
And then you can choose one of the default pictures or browse through your files for your own

Hope This Helps

XLR8,
From

Comment: This is a programming site.  The OP wants to know how to change the user picture from his own application, not how to change it using the GUI.